# Python regular expression simple OR condition doesn't work?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a simple regular expression in Python that recognizes either a comma or a newline, to be used as a delimiter and split() text.

I have tried the following:

```
delim = r'[,\n]'
delim = r'[\n,]'
delim = r',|\n'
delim = r'[,|\n]'
delim = r'(,\n)'
```

None of these work. The split() works fine if I make it just one or the other, such as...

```
delim = r','
delim = r'\n'
```

But not if I try and do both.

What am I missing here?

Thank you for your input.

Whole code:

```
    data = "abc,def\nghi"
    delim = r'[,\n]'
    values = data.split(delim)
    print(values)
```

Comment: You are not using a `re.split`: use `values = re.split(delim, data)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `str.split()`, which doesn't take a regex as an argument.

Try using `re.compile` on your regex string, and then using that object for the split:

```
import re

data = "abc,def\nghi"
delim = re.compile(r'[,\n]')
values = delim.split(data)
print(values)
```

Yields:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Comment: or `re.split(r'[,\n]', data)`

Comment: Thank you! I was calling split on the wrong variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is bult-in python re module

```
import re

data = "abc,def\nghi"

re.split(",|\n", data)
Out[3]: ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

You can enter the delimiter list as such ",|\n|;|whatever|whatever2"

Comment: A so common "satellite" answer :) The alternation is much less efficient than a character class if the delimiters are single characters.

Comment: True:

%timeit(re.split(",|\n", data))
1.37 µs per loop

%timeit(re.split("[,\n]", data))
 1.44 µs per loop

delim = re.compile(r'[,\n]')
%timeit(delim.split(data))
 631 ns per loop